# C# WPF datagrid check all button only works half the time

Tags: c#, wpf

**SOLVED**: Forgot the following in the datagrid

```xml
EnableRowVirtualization="false"
```

**UPDATE:** Using a message box to see when the issue happens it happens as soon as the tick box is the one outside of the screen. same happens when scrolling past the first entry

Rather stumped why only sometimes it will return null and sometimes work perfectly fine without issue.

The data is imported via a list that is populated from another method with a single value, so that shouldn't be causing any issues.

```cs
public bool chkbox = false;


        private void CheckAll(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkbox == false)
            {
                StringBuilder sbTemp = new StringBuilder();

                for (int index = 0; index <= NameGrid.Items.Count - 1; index++)
                {
                    FrameworkElement item = NameGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(NameGrid.Items[index]);
                    DataGridTemplateColumn temp = (NameGrid.Columns[0] as DataGridTemplateColumn);
                    CheckBox cb = temp.CellTemplate.FindName("PrintCheckBox", item) as CheckBox;
                    cb.IsChecked = true;

                }
                chkbox = true;
            }
            else
            {

                StringBuilder sbTemp = new StringBuilder();

                for (int index = 0; index <= NameGrid.Items.Count - 1; index++)
                {
                    FrameworkElement item = NameGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(NameGrid.Items[index]);
                    DataGridTemplateColumn temp = (NameGrid.Columns[0] as DataGridTemplateColumn);
                    CheckBox cb = temp.CellTemplate.FindName("PrintCheckBox", item) as CheckBox;
                    cb.IsChecked = false;

                }
                chkbox = false;
            }

        }
```

Datagrid XML

```xml
<DataGrid Name="NameGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <CheckBox Content="Include" Click="CheckAll"/>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Name="PrintCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   Margin="45 2 0 0"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"Width="100"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: As a guess: if you'd put the _"SOLVED: "_ part into a new Answer to self, your Question could suit the SO philosophy better

Answer (score 0):

insert

```xml
EnableRowVirtualization="false"
```

Inside of datagrid view main controller